# Python handling floating point with multiply float

Tags: python, floating-point

I encountered a floating point problem when dealing with flow:

```
a = "0.0003"
b = pow(10, 4)

c = int(float(a) * b)) // int so i don't want the decimal places behind
```

i got the following result `2.9999999999999996` which is wrong

I also tried decimal:

```
c = int(Decimal(a) * Decimal(pow(10, 4)))
```

but still got the wrong result `2.999999999999999737189393390`

Expected result is 3

In Javascript we can use `bignumber.js`

Is there a way i can avoid this kind of problem in python? maybe some library like in javascript
Thanks

Comment: The Decimal version doesn't give you that wrong result.

Comment: @superbrain you are correct, my bad i was passing a as float into it instead of a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure a is the string, not the float. Then it should work.

```
int(Decimal('0.0003') * pow(10, 4))
# returns 3
```